# UltraEdit непонятные символы в HEX

Tags: hex

В общем дали мне задание исправить ошибки в коде. Сам код представлен в HEX-кодировке. Я запустил его с помощью UltraEdit, как было предложено. Но проблема в том, что часть текста нормальная, а часть непонятные иероглифы. И как понять, где искать ошибку не понятно. Есть ли какие нибудь предложения по тому, как сделать код читабельным или хотя бы понять, что там?

Пример кода ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: по вашему вопросу довольно сложно сделать выводы, недостаточно информации. Скорее всего за данными байтами кроется кириллица или бинарники

Comment: `дали мне задание исправить ошибки в коде` вот кто дал, тот пусть и объясняет , и как там можно поправить ошибки!? Это можно сделать декомпилировав программу с дальнейшим исправлением и сборкой, но это не ваш случай, однозначно :) отложите эту затею в сторону. Или файл является архивом? Название файла хоть объявите.

Comment: Там ехешник с программой для миографа)такое точно в интернете не найти